# Play/Pause Button doesn't appear in Carplay Dashboard

Tags: ios, audio, carplay

i have a radio app and integrated with carplay. In Carplay Dashboard, i only see the album cover image and stop button. I want to show play/pause and skip buttons in Dashboard. Can you help me if you know anything about this station?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the MPRemoteCommandCenter to access remote media control commands. Check out the [docs for MPRemoteCommandCenter here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpremotecommandcenter).

You can then enable and disable certain commands for car play by setting or unsetting `isEnabled` and by adding a target for certain commands using `addTarget`.

For example, to add a pause command with a target and to disable the seek backward command you would do something like this:

```
let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { (_) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in

    // Pause your media player

    return .success
}

commandCenter.seekBackwardCommand.isEnabled = false
```